# PHP Yii separating mark up code

Tags: php, web, yii

I am pretty new to web programming and I am using **PHP Yii** as the MVC framework.

I have the view pages in which I get the required data from model or controller. And when I want to design some layout in the view (say a list of divs) with the data coming from `Yii::Model::MyModel::FindAll()`. The data from the model is represented in the list of divs. I am currently doing this with mixing server side code and HTML (using  tags) and it looks ugly.

I did some web programming 10 years before and I used this technique with jsp, but is there a clean way to do this? I know I can use PHP widgets, but aren't they only for reusable views?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use CListView, CGridView to bind your data into list or gird

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Comment: Yes(this is like a widget but already built in) and it also needs a view file(seperate from the main page) where I have to mix the server side code and HTML markup? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Agreed. This is the cleanest way to go. Try running a Gii CRUD builder if you need some example code to get you started

Comment: Thanks. I used the CRUD builder and added standard edit, list and add pages. But the question i had is to display some other customized view (like a carousel with list of divs) and I was looking to see if there is a better approach. Looks like I have to stick to mixing HTML and PHP tags.

Comment: I think if you do not want to code any more, you must use 3rd party extension such as: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edatatables (i've not test it yet).